# Issues connecting Raspberry Pi 1B+ with RISC OS to laptop

Tags: ssh, riscos

I've been trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 1B+ to my laptop as it is usually done (HDMI, Ethernet cable and USB with power adaptor) and I can't find it on my computer (laptop with Ubuntu 19.04).

I tried connecting with SSH but login fails, I've been looking for both user and password but it looks like there is none of them default.

I can't use NOOBS because I'm using a specific RISC OS image provided by my college to follow the subject.

I hope somebody can give me a solution on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: RISC OS is hardly main stream on the Pi.  It has only a small number of users.  Why do you think SSH or similar is supported?

Comment: I'm pretty new to RPi, I didn't even know about that

Comment: I believe you are more likely to get a response if you post a question at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=55